# Error "Expected Ext.Base#getX to be Defined"

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I'm having this error

> Expected Ext.Base#getX to be Defined

after building production version(sencha app build production). 
Test version works fine.

Additional details: 
error call stack coming from addDeprecations, and has following info

```
getPageX:"getX"
getPageY:"getY"
version:"4.0"
```

Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? The deprecations are only added in `modern`.

Comment: it's classic tooltik, none of there deprecated methods above are used

Comment: issue is gone when js optimizer is disabled
app.output.js.optimize=false